# SQL dealing with multilevel time series data

Tags: sql, t-sql

**Question**

I'm interested in finding out how many people switched jobs with their current employer in a given year. I know advanced SQL concepts but lack experience. So I'm interested in the way I should go about this. The main challenge for me is the fact that the data is multilevel (employers > persons > jobs) combined with the time interval constraints.

The data looks something like this:

```
| person | employer | job_title | started | stopped |
----------------------------------------------------- 
| p1     | e1       | j1        | t1      | t2      |
| p1     | e1       | j2        | t3      | t4      |
| p1     | e1       | j3        | t5      | t6      |
| p2     | e2       | j1        | t5      | t6      |
| p2     | e2       | j4        | t7      | t8      |
| p3     | e3       | j5        | t7      | t8      |
| p3     | e4       | j6        | t9      | t10     |
```

I need a SQL query that extracts the count of job switches within the same company (employer) during each calendar year.

- `t` values are year-month combinations stored as integers (202208)
- The target variable is "switching jobs within the same employer in a given year". This is defined as having the end date of `job_a` and the start date of `job_b` in the same calendar year `x`, with `job_a` and `job_b` of `person_a` both being at `employer_a`

**Example responses**

For a given time interval X.

1. Let's say that t1 -> t4 fall within X, but t5 -> t10 do not. Then the output should be `1`, as only `p1` switched jobs before t5.
2. If we say that t1 -> t10 all fall within X, the output should be `2`, as both `p1` and `p2` switched jobs within the same company. `p3` is excluded, as she switched jobs, but not within the same company.

Comment: Actual sample data with real dates might help, as well as expected results

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Two examples of expected results were in 'Example responses', Regarding the dates, next time I'll make sure to post some random integers for dates instead of the t1, t2, etc. .

Comment: No we need to see a proper table, maybe try doing [markdown table](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356997/new-feature-table-support) alternatively `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statements would help even more. We also need expected results as a table. Basically, we need to *see* what you want, rather than you just describing it, otherwise it's hard to visualize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try the following:

```
Select Sum(d.chk) as Result
From 
(
  Select distinct person,
   Case When
    Count(*) Over (Partition By person,employer ) <>
    Count(*) Over (Partition By person,employer,job_title) 
   Then 1 Else 0
  End as chk
 From Emps
 Where started>='2015-10-10' and stopped <='2022-08-16'
) d
```

`Count(*) Over (Partition By person, employer )` will count how many times the employee stayed in the same company whatever his position was.

`Count(*) Over (Partition By person, employer, job_title)` will count how many times the employee position changed within the same company.

If the two counts are not equal, means that the employee position has been changed within the same company.

See a demo from [*db<>fiddle*](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=ac9db70480de4e805b46af11b36ab65e).

Comment: Cheers for your clear answer! With a few minor tweaks this worked like a charm. Now I know how to handle this kind of problem.

Comment: Happy for that, Good Luck.